# How can I print WebView after it loading in MacOS App

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to Print WebView in Print-Panel from Mac OS App. How to show WebView content in Print-Panel.

This is for printing WebView, I've tried to print "https://www.google.com" in Print Panel after loading into WebView and always it seems blank page in Print.

```
var wbView: WKWebView!
let preferences = WKPreferences()
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true

    configuration.preferences = preferences

    wbView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
    self.view.addSubview(wbView)
    wbView.navigationDelegate = self
    wbView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))

}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!){

       wbView.printView(self)
//     let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view:  wbView)
//     printOperation.run()

    }

}
```

I tried in two ways to Print by using 
1. wbView.printView()
2.  let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view:  badgeView)
           printOperation.run()

But it is not working in above both the cases.

Please suggest any solution for this, Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one Print all WKWebView On AND Offscreen content OSX and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319295/how-does-one-print-all-wkwebview-on-and-offscreen-content-osx-and-ios) and [Printing contents of WKWebView (OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236929/printing-contents-of-wkwebview-os-x)

Comment: @Willeke,  
But, in your answer "'WebFrameLoadDelegate' was deprecated in OS X 10.14"

Comment: You can manually select the contents in the view and then choose print from file menu.